# NetInstall установка Centos8 выдаёт ошибку error setting up base repository

Tags: centos, установка, centos8

Очень не хотелось скачивать полный DVD-дистрибутив centos8, поэтому выбрал NetInstall-образ (574 мб), однако при установке с него получаю ошибку error setting up base repository после того, как входишь в настройки installation source и оставляешь дефолтный вариант "ближайшее зеркало".

Что не так? Как поправить? Качать полный DVD не предлагать.

Answer (score 0):

С учётом того, что centos не хочет создавать видимость того, что они как-то контролируют и проверяют большое число зеркал и что загрузка часто идёт по небезопасным протоколам -- придётся вбивать адрес вручную.

Самое главное: проверяйте доступность этого адреса, просто открыв его в браузере!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я долго удивлялся что не так, когда раз пять вставлял адрес и до меня не доходило, что то, что я вставляю "немного" отличается. Замыленный взгляд сличая два url'а не обращал внимания что во вставленном нет слова /BaseOs/

Репозиториев много, инструкций разных много. Где-то советуют один адрес, где-то с http, где-то без, где-то нужен `/` на конце где-то нет... Лучше всего: зайдите руками на список репозиториев, выберите себе подходящий, проверьте ссылку в браузере.

Я остановился на варианте: mirror.yandex.ru/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/ (протокол: https, тип url: repository url).

Протокол выбирать строго в переключателе, в адресной строке не парсится.

Вот один из вариантов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По теме:

- https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=16456
- https://youtu.be/nNNkZ0I2DFw?t=435
- https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=16633